# ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred When try to connect from host OS

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ora-12170

I have Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production installed on virtual machine(VirtualBox, OS: Oracle Linux 7).

All going normal, when I try to connect from the virtual machine where oracle database installed. (sqlplus sys/sys_password@192.168.56.101/XE as sysdba).

But I have **ORA-12170** error when I try to connect to oracle from the host OS (Windown 7 x64) by using the same command.

ping 192.168.56.101 command from host OS is successfull.

Now I'm using host only network, but I had same results with bridged connection.

Here is my tnslistener.ora file:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
 (SID_LIST =
  (SID_DESC =
   (SID_NAME = XE)
   (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe)
  )
  (SID_DESC =
   (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
   (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe)
   (PROGRAM = extproc)
  )
)

LISTENER =
 (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
  (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost.localdomain)(PORT = 1521))
  )
 )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess you should have in your listener definition network address of the host instead of 'localhost'

Answer (score 0):

It seems your listener is incorrectly configured. If you use localhost.localdomain as HOST then the listener will bind to **loopback interface only**.

Try to use **actual IP** address instead of localhost.localdomain. Also you can use **0.0.0.0** as HOST so the listener will bind to any interface to avoid hardcoded IP address, but I don't recommend this on production server.

Also check if your guest firewall does allow TCP communication on 1521 port.

Following is my working listener.ora:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```